# how to get same geo code for an address which is in bing map through bing map API?

Tags: bing, bing-api, bing-maps

I have an address which shows correct correct place in bingmap. When I request geo code for same address using Unstructured URL API, it sends different geo location

address:
**86 Oakleaf Dr Meadow Valley, CA 95956**
[image]

when I request through bing map api

*https://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Locations?CountryRegion=us&adminDistrict=CA&locality=Meadow%20Valley&postalCode=95956&addressLine=86%20Oakleaf%20Dr&output=json&key=BingmapKey*

It result somewhere here

[image]

am I missing anything in API request? (I have valid bing key)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed API calling 
***Find a Location by Address*** to ***Find a Location by Query*** and it sends same geo location which when we search address in bingmap website.

No other solution I could found in ***Find a Location by Address*** API.

```
var url = "https://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Locations?query=" 
+ encodeURIComponent('Oakleaf Dr Meadow Valley CA 95956 United States')
+ "&incl=queryParse"
+ "&output=json"
+ "&key=" + BingmapKey
```

Answer (score 0):

```
https://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Locations?CountryRegion=us&adminDistrict=CA&locality=Meadow%20Valley&postalCode=95956&addressLine=86%20Oakleaf%20Dr.&output=json&key=BingMapsKey
```

What you have seems right, I just added a period after the 'Dr' and it changed it to the correct location you wanted.

Comment: These address are generated by a system. We cant force to add period `.` add to the addresses